# Usage of verb "trovare"

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use "trova" like this?

> Sono un tenore naturale che trova le note basse un po' difficili.

And basse means low?

Answer (score 2):

Provided you use *trova* and not *trovo*, the phrase is grammatically correct and in this case trova means the tenor finds it difficult to deal with low (or bass) notes.

The meaning of [trovare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trovare/) that suits for this context is 3b which you can find in the Treccani's dictionary:

> 3b. ***Per esprimere l’impressione che qualcuno o qualcosa produce, e
> quindi col sign. di riconoscere, riscontrare all’osservazione o
> all’esame***: *il dottore mi trova migliorato, peggiorato, guarito; ti
> trovo meglio oggi; come mi trovi stamani?; ti trovo un po’ ingrassato,
> assai dimagrito; l’ultima volta che lo vidi, lo trovai molto
> invecchiato; avendo un dì presso a Peretola una gru ammazzata,
> trovandola grassa e giovane, quella mandò a un suo buon cuoco ...
> dicendo che a cena l’arrostisse* (Boccaccio); o sperimentare
> direttamente: *me l’avevano descritto come un orso, io invece l’ho
> trovato gentilissimo; attribuire una qualità con giudizio soggettivo:
> la trovo bella, simpatica; venendo poi a esaminarla in particolare,
> notavan chi un difetto, chi un altro: e ci furon fin quelli che la
> trovarono brutta affatto* (Manzoni); *trovi buono questo vino?; ho
> assaggiato il formaggio e l’ho trovato eccellente; ho trovato il conto
> piuttosto caro; trovi divertente questa commedia?; trovo lo scherzo di
> pessimo gusto;* seguito da prop. oggettiva: trovo che hai ragione; non
> trovi di esagerare?; anche, riconoscere in seguito a indagine, e
> quindi dichiarare con giudizio espresso: *fu trovato innocente,
> colpevole.*

This means to express the impression that someone or something produces,  with the meaning of *to identify, to encounter when obeserving or examining something*.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "trovare" is the same doable in English with "find" like in

> He finds rational equations too difficult.

Your sentence in English is (translated with Google translator)

> I am a natural tenor who finds the low notes a little difficult

which corresponds to Italian "Sono un tenore naturale che trova le note basse un po' difficili" (it's a literal translation).

Comment: So it is "who finds" and not "who find"? This is why trova is correct. I could have written "Trovo le note basse un po' difficili". Then "trovo" would be correct?

Comment: Yes, @Hank: in this sentence "trovo" is correct.